# Decipher any string that is passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, encryption

I am attempting this question on Codewars. I am not sure if am doing it right. Here is the question:

You are given a secret message you need to decipher. Here are the things you need to know to decipher it:

For each word:

```
the second and the last letter is switched (e.g. Hello becomes Holle)
the first letter is replaced by its character code (e.g. H becomes 72)
```

Note: there are no special characters used, only letters and spaces:

```
decipherThis('72olle 103doo 100ya'); // 'Hello good day'
decipherThis('82yade 115te 103o'); // 'Ready set go'
```

Now I have written this piece of code:

```
function decipherThis(str)
{
  var msg = [];
  msg.push(str.charCodeAt(0));
  for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++) 
  {
    if (str[1] == true && str[1] != str[str.length]) 
    {
      msg.push(str[str.length]);
      //str[1] = str[str.length]);
      var news = str;
      for (var j = 0; j<news.length; j++) 
      {
        news[1] = news[news.length];
        const newNew = delete news[0][1];

        msg.push(newNew);
      }
    }
  }
  return msg;
}; 

var google = "hello"

decipherThis(google)
```

I am getting an error and I think I have created it for a single word. It does not understand words after blank spaces. Please help me fix this.
This is the error traceback:

```
  Response received but no data was written to STDOUT or STDERR.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change `characterCodeAt` to  `charCodeAt` and it will work.

`characterCodeAt` is not a valid method of a String class

Answer (score 0):

The error is not Javascript related. It might occur because the `decipherThis()` function is returning an array instead of a string.

You could loop the original string backwards until the second character and concatonate it to the charcode of the first character like this:

```
function decipherThis(str)
{
  var cipher = '',
      words = str.split(' ');

  for(var w = 0; w < words.length; w++) {
    cipher += ' '+words[w].charCodeAt(0);
    for(var i = words[w].length-1; i > 0; i--) {
      cipher += words[w][i];
    }
  }
  return cipher.trim();
}
```